# Duplicate lines in a text file multiple times based on a string and alter duplicated lines

Tags: powershell

SHORT: I am trying to duplicate lines in all files in a folder based on a certain string and then replace original strings in duplicated lines only.

Contents of the original text file (there are double quotes in the file):

```
"K:\FILE1.ini"
"K:\FILE1.cfg"
"K:\FILE100.cfg"
```

I want to duplicate the entire line 4 times only if a string ".ini" is present in a line.

After duplicating the line, I want to change the string in those duplicated lines (original line stays the same) to: for example, ".inf", ".bat", ".cmd", ".mov".

So the expected result of the script is as follows:

```
"K:\FILE1.ini"
"K:\FILE1.inf"
"K:\FILE1.bat"
"K:\FILE1.cmd"
"K:\FILE1.mov"
"K:\FILE1.cfg"
"K:\FILE100.cfg"
```

Those files are small, so using streams is not neccessary.

I am at the beginning of my PowerShell journey, but thanks to this community, I already know how to replace string in files recursively:

```
$directory = "K:\PS"
Get-ChildItem $directory -file -recurse -include *.txt | 
    ForEach-Object {
        (Get-Content $_.FullName) -replace ".ini",".inf" |
            Set-Content $_.FullName
    }
```

but I have no idea how to duplicate certain lines multiple times and handle multiple string replacements in those duplicated lines.

**Yet ;)**

Could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do not use replace.  Write to new text file.  Read each line of original file in ForEach and then write the original and new lines to new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this with the operator `-replace` you can do:

```
#Define strings to replace pattern with
$2replace = @('.inf','.bat','.cmd','.mov','.ini')
#Get files, use filter instead of include = faster
get-childitem -path [path] -recurse -filter '*.txt' | %{
    $cFile = $_
    #add new strings to array newData
    $newData = @(
        #Read file
        get-content $_.fullname | %{
            #If line matches .ini
            If ($_ -match '\.ini'){
                $cstring = $_
                #Add new strings
                $2replace  | %{
                    #Output new strings
                    $cstring -replace '\.ini',$_
                }
            }
            #output current string
            Else{
                $_
            }
        }
    )
    #Write to disk
    $newData | set-content $cFile.fullname
}
```

This gives you the following output:

```
$newdata
"K:\FILE1.inf"
"K:\FILE1.bat"
"K:\FILE1.cmd"
"K:\FILE1.mov"
"K:\FILE1.ini"
"K:\FILE1.cfg"
"K:\FILE100.cfg"
```

Comment: As I thought, this is a quite advanced script, completely out of reach for a beginner like me. I knew that an array should be used for all those string to replace. I noticed that the clarity of your script lets me understand what it does.
New things to look up after reading your script: 
1. What "@(" means.
2. What "%{" is used for.
Thank you, this script will make my life easier.

Comment: @() = defines an array; % = foreach-object